# Linq order by random without GUID

Tags: c#, linq, random

Need to order by random using linq and I can't use GUID.NewGuid(), I need something like this: .OrderBy(x => "somestring").

a mobile app is suppose to generate a random string and call my WebApi and because I maintained paging mobile app will sends the same random string but a different page number so every time it sends that random string ordering should be the same but different skip ... .

how is this possible? if not a string but maybe a number or anything fixed for every linq query.

Edit:

this is the WebApi

```
[Route("GetChannels/{id}/{word}/{page}/{randomstring}")]
public IEnumerable<Channels> GetChannels(int id, string word, int page, string randomstring)
    {

   ...

    if (canPage)
       {                
            var channels = db.Channels.Where(x => (id == 0) || (x.CategoryId == id))
            .Where(q => word == "0" ||
            (q.Title.Contains(word) || q.Desc.Contains(word)))
            .OrderBy(x => randomstring).Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
        }

...
```

Comment: Can you add some punctuations to your problem description? As it currently written it's not clear what you have now, how you call api, and what you expect to get

Comment: Can I ask why you doing want GUID?  I think the Jon Skeet  answer uses GUIDs

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, I added more details

Comment: @farhang67 `.OrderBy(x => randomstring)` will return unordered sequence, because `randomstring` is same for all items. Can you describe what are yout trying to achieve?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I want to show results to the mobile app users with random order everytime they open the app so I can generate some string for ordering and send it to server and when they page the app will send the same string so the ordering will be the same but with different page number ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return results in random order, but that order will be the same if you are sending same string from client, then you can use [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class to get pseudo-random order. This random generator can accept *seed* - a value, which is used to calculate starting value of pseudo-random sequence. Thus you are passing `string` you can use it's hash code to get integer value for seed:

```
        var seed = randomstring.GetHashCode();
        var random = new Random(seed);

        var channels = db.Channels
           .Where(x => (id == 0) || (x.CategoryId == id))
           .Where(q => word == "0" || (q.Title.Contains(word) || q.Desc.Contains(word)))
           .AsEnumerable() // randomizing should happen on client side
           .OrderBy(x => random.Next())
           .Skip(skip)
           .Take(pageSize)
           .ToList();
```

Comment: A nice solution, but one caveat is that if the list changes at all between the first call and any subsequent paging calls then the list will get totally changed.  So if you are looking at something that changes often this won't work very well.  Actually, since most databases don't guarantee order if no `orderby` is specified, it is quite possible for this to break even if no records are changed...

Comment: You can fix the later issue by placing `.OrderBy(x=>x.id)` before the `.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: @RobertMcKee, unfortunately, this will not work.You cannot handle adding items and saving original order of original items. E.g. you have items `1,2,3`. Which were ordered as `2,1,3`. One more item was added. You want to preserve original ordering and return `2,1,3,4`. Next item comes. You want to preserve original ordering and you get `2,1,3,4,5`. I.e. all future items will not be shuffled. They will be returned  in the order they have been added.

Comment: Sort of, but you can maintain the relative order of items if an item is returned in a different order or with an item inserted/removed from the middle of the result.  If your original query returned `1,2,3` and `2` is removed, then `3` will be assigned the random number that `2` used to, which would put it in a completely different spot than it originally was.

Comment: One small issue is that `GetHashCode` is guarenteed to return the same value on different implementations of the framework - 32 vs 64 or core, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @Sergey's already excellent answer and resolving a few minor corner cases:

```
    var channels = db.Channels.AsQueryable();

    #region filtering
      if (id!=0)
        channels = channels.Where(x=>x.CategoryId == id);
      if (word!="0")
        channels = channels.Where(x=>x.Title.Contains(word) || x.Desc.Contains(word));
    #endregion filtering

    #region server-side ordering
      channels = channels.OrderBy(x=>x.id);
    #endregion server-side ordering

    #region client-side ordering
      var seed = randomstring.GetHashCode();
      var random = new Random(seed);
      var channelList = channels.ToList(); // force client side
      var maxid = channelList.Select(x=>id).Max();
      var keys = Enumerable
        .Range(0,maxid)
        .ToDictionary(x=>x,x=>random.Next());

      var sorted = channelList
        .OrderBy(x=>keys[x.id]);
    #endregion client-side ordering

    #region paging
      var results = sorted
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
    #endregion paging
```

In this case, if a record is added (new higher id), or deleted (id removed) then the order will be maintained as if the record always existed, so the results may shift, but won't be completely reordered.  Also performance will likely be bad if the channel's id is large.

Actually for most cases, I would just suggest using a random number, generating the unpaged results, then stuffing the results into cache using that key for subsequent paging operations (if sending the entire result unpaged to the client isn't an option).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Random rand = new Random();
            List<string> input = new List<string>();
            var results = input.Select(x => new { x = x, r = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.r).Select(x => x.x);
```